# Why is there a left space on the left of linear layout?

Tags: android, constraints, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

[image: immage of android studio design]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#019032"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Falesie in Italia" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm trying to add a Toolbar on my app and i have a little space on the left of linear layout.

This is the code of my main activity layout, i tried to change padding and margin of all the element but the situation doasn't change.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Probably issue with preview, Goto File > Invalidate & Restart

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried your suggestion but i still have the space.

Comment: It is strange!  Everything seems right

Comment: There are no problems with your code. Run it, it should work fine.The layout inspector does things like this from time to time. I just close the inspector and open it up again

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not only present in the preview, but also in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
 app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
 app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
 android:padding="0dp"
```

it will be like this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Preview in my Android Studio
The problem is with caches

Try

- Copy the file content
- Delete the file
- File > Invalidate & Restart
- Gradle sync
- Create new file with different name
- Check the preview
- Run the app and check
- Rename to original name

If this doesnt work

- Close android studio completely
  (Check task manager and end task if its still running)
- Enter `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\caches` in explorer and delete the caches folder
  [image]
- Go to your project root and delete `.idea`, `.gradle` and `build` folders
  [image]
- Open android studio

Comment: Hi Omka, i just tried your solution step by step but still have the problem.

Comment: Please try the updated answer

Comment: The problem with the default values of toolbar as the @imaluris said it appear also in the app not only the preview so that mean the problem not with build files he need only to set the default values of padding and content inset 0 or any he need to control the space

Comment: Hello guys, i momentarily solved by adding android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp" in ToolBar item.